# Sylius Product Bundle Installation

Tags: symfony, installation, bundle, product, sylius

I'm trying to install Sylius Product Bundle into my fresh Symfony project.
I followed installation documentation step by step, and still getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in DoctrineTargetEntitiesResolver.php line 91:
The class sylius.model.product_variant.class does not exist.
```

My composer.json after composer require sylius/product-bundle

```
{
    ..., 
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sylius/product-bundle": "^0.15.0"

    },
    ...
}
```

AppKernel.php

```
$bundles = array(

            new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            new WhiteOctober\PagerfantaBundle\WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle(),
            new Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\SyliusProductBundle(),
            new Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle(),
            new Sylius\Bundle\AttributeBundle\SyliusAttributeBundle(),

            ...
```

config.yml

```
sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm # Configure the doctrine orm driver used in the documentation.

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
            timestampable: true
```

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

sylius_product:
    resource: "@SyliusProductBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Any ideas how to bypass this problem?

**Update:**
If I install 0.19.0 version error changes to:

```
ServiceNotFoundException in ContainerBuilder.php line 816:
You have requested a non-existent service "sylius.factory.product_variant".
```

Comment: Is it possible this is related to: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/3647 ?